# Codeigniter Form Validation always returns false

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I've spent so much time on this one I think I've gone code-blind. The form validation is always returning FALSE on run and I can't figure out the reason.

The new_map() function displays first the form, on submit of the form (with value set in the map_name field of course), the form validation run returns false and the form is reset with no errors displayed however. What am I missing??

Controller:

```
public function new_map()
{
    $data['extra_assets']['js'][] = 'app/admin/maps.js';

    $data['title'] = 'Add Map';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('map_name', 'Map name', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {  
        $this->load_admin_view('admin/ae_map', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        $this->load->model('maps_model');
        echo 'inside true';exit;
        // Upload map
        if ($this->maps_model->upload_map())
        {
            redirect(site_url('admin/maps'));
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public function upload_map()
{
    $config['upload_path'] = root_path() . 'space/maps/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    $map_name = $this->input->post('map_name');

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('map_file'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        echo $this->upload->display_errors();exit;
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        // Insert map into database
        $options = array(
                    'm_file' => $data['upload_data']['file_name'],
                    'm_name' => $map_name
                 );
        $this->insert_map($options);

        // Create a thumbnail of this map
        $this->generate_map_thumb($data['upload_data']['file_name']);
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

View:

```
<div class="modalContent" style="width: 300px; height: 250px;">
<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>

<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

<div id="MAP_FORM" class="formListing">
    <?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/new_map'); ?>

    <ul>
        <li>        
            <div><label>File: </label></div>
            <div><span><input type="file" id="MAP_FILE" name="map_file" /></span></div>
        </li>
        <li>      
            <div><label>Name: </label></div>
            <div><span><input type="text" id="MAP_NAME" name="map_name" value="" /></span></div>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="SUBMIT_MAP" name="submit_map" />

    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is your form validation taking place in the model? It should be in the controller. But anyways, let me take a look at what actually is happening! Also, why is there a redirect statement in the model. These statements are a part of the controller.

Comment: I'm guessing that the model and controller code have been labelled the wrong way around- unless there is another `new_map` function in the controller?

Comment: Sorry guys! indeed they have been labeled the other way around. I'll switch the labeling right away.

Comment: Well the form is working now, although I wish I could figure out what I changed in case I face a similar issue in the future. 

Sorry for the confusion the labeling caused. Now all I need to do I guess is create a callback function to validate the uploaded file before I call the model. I'm reluctant to do so however, as all this mess started with me trying to do just that :)

Answer (score 5):

Im sorry if my answer is not very helpful, but im not allowed to add comments yet.

It seems that your interplay of controllers, models and libraries is upside down. Remember that all form validations should take place in the controller, as Aniket said. And all your database interactions should take place in models.

The reason IF statement is failing is because it does not complete an upload, and it doesnt do that, because you havent told the controlled to even attempt an upload.

Try to rework your controller from this perspective. Also, you should not define == FALSE when you run form validation. Sometimes it can create problems. Just use `if (!$this->form_validation->run())`.

Comment: I had just switched the labels in my question by mistake (the code for the controller was actually the model's, and vice versa!).

Comment: I just tried my code now again and before I could even remove == FALSE, the form suddenly worked. For the life of me I can't figure out why the form wasn't submitting and why it's working now when I don't seem to have changed anything.

I'm new to MVC and CodeIgniter, but I don't think there's anything wrong with my code (now that the labels are fixed at least :o) ) In any case, thanks for the help! It was driving me insane!!